# history + display date and time for each command

Tags: bash, rhel, command, command-history

we have redhat Linux machine version 7.2

when we type history we get the history but without date and time

```
    1  ifconfig
    2  cd /etc/udev/rules.d/
    3  ls
    4  cat 99-vmware-scsi-udev.rules
    5  nano /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ethde032
    6  ifconfig
    7  service libvirtd statua
    8  service libvirtd status
    9  chkconfig -list | grep -i lib
   10  chkconfig -list
   11  chkconfig
   17  virsh net-destroy default
   18  virsh net-undefine default
   19  serice libvrtd
   20  serice libvirtd stop
   21  service libvirtd stop
   22  service libvirtd status
```

how to display from history command also the date & time for each number

Comment: And https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/87740 for the inevitable follow-up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i used this command and it worked:
`echo 'export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "' >> ~/.bashrc ; source ~/.bashrc`
(for more details of how this command works read links in  above comments)